# How to restore the previous version of a ClickOnce app programmatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, deployment, clickonce

I'm trying to build a mechanism that will rollback my application deployment to the previous version, on user demand.

I'm using ClickOnce network deploy strategy.

I've tried to find a reference to call win API to do it for me without this user intervention window:

[image]

I didn't find a clickonce API that does this work for me, so, I'm looking for a winAPI method that does the trick.

Is there are some reference to do that?

Comment: In [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff369721.aspx), take a look at this part: *How to programmatically uninstall a Click Once application and install a new version*

Comment: Ok, tks @RezaAghaei. On my case, i need just restore previous version instead reinstall :/

Comment: @ViniciusGonçalves: What's the difference between *"restoring"* and *"reinstalling"* a particular version of your software? And how do you know, that the *Restore application to the previous state* option doesn't reinstall a previous version?

Comment: @IInspectable: Five versions of the app was installed. Now, the user is installing the version 6, after that, restore previous state will rollback to version 5 instead of last or first version. I've tested it.

Comment: As I said, *"'reinstalling' a **particular** version"*. Uninstalling version 6 followed by reinstalling version 5 will have the same effect as rolling back to previous version from version 6. Or am I misunderstanding the question?